# any trick to combine 2 Item[] expressions to one expression for the purpose of use in a macro?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

V 8.04.  This is in the context of `Manipulate` use only.

Here is a simple example of using an Item to place controls in different places in the UI using Manipulate

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> 100],
 Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1,ImageSize->Tiny}],ControlPlacement->Left],
 Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1,ImageSize->Tiny}],ControlPlacement->Right]
 ]
```

[image]

However, I am using Leonid's macro method (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551647/how-to-define-part-of-a-manipulate-control-variable-definition-to-reduce-code-du) ) to help me build my UI controls, so I'd like to do something like

```
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}],

 Evaluate@With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny},

   Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1, im}],ControlPlacement -> Left],
   Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Right]

   ]    
 ]
```

The above does NOT work, because we no longer have ONE expression to make `With` happy, which has the syntax

```
 With[{x=x0}, expression ]
```

And in the above, the 2 `Item`s are now not ONE expression, but 2.

This problem shows up only when I want to use `Item` to control placement. Otherwise, I would use `Grid[]` and combine my different things inside the `Grid`, and then the problem is solved.

But I can't of course use `Item` inside grid for purposes of making each `Item` locate in different place. The whole `Grid` has to be in one place.

I thought wrapping the 2 Items inside a `Sequence[]` might work but it does not.

**question is: Any trick to combine the above 2 Items into ONE expression to make With happy?**

Currently I solve this problem in my UI by simply breaking things into 2 separate `With`s like this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}],

 Evaluate@With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny},
   Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], 
    ControlPlacement -> Left]
   ],

 Evaluate@With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny},
   Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], 
    ControlPlacement -> Right]
   ]

 ]
```

And it works fine.

But of course, in the above, I lose *some* of the benefits of using macro names to share among many control construction code.

**update 12/26/11 8:37 PM**

Here is an example, using one macro inside another. I think it is a Hold issue. The trick shown below is not working for this. Will try to figure it out: (In practice, I use 2 levels macros, as I define some macros at one level, and use them to build a higher level macros in the second level. here I only show very simple example of what I mean)

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}],

 Evaluate@With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny},

   Evaluate@With[{},

     ## &[
      Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Left],
      Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Right]
      ]

     ]
   ]
 ]
```

I am almost sure I need a `HoldAll` thing to insert in the right place to sort this one out. Will try to figure it out and report here. Coffee is almost done ;)

**update 9 pm**

Ok, MrWizard showed me the problem with above. I should *not* have an Evaluate on the inner macros. I forgot about this. Here it is now, it works fine:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}],

 Evaluate@With[{},

   With[{},
    ## &[
     Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1}], ControlPlacement -> Left], 
     Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1}], ControlPlacement -> Right]
     ]

    ](*close second With*)
   ](*close first With*)

 ](*close Manipulate*)
```

Thanks for the answer, both very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget about `Sequence` and `Apply`.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}],
 Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny},
    Hold[
     Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Left],
     Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Right]
    ]
   ]
]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Brett's answer made me realize the same thing can be done more tersely like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}],
 Evaluate @ With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny},
   ## &[
    Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Left], 
    Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Right]
   ]
  ]
]
```

Since `With` does not have `SequenceHold` attribute we cannot do simply Sequence[Item, Item], but we can use `## &[Item, Item]` because `&` delays the evaluation.

Comment: @MrWizard, +100, I am not sure now how this works, I need to surgically break it up and study it to figure out, but it works!  thanks.

Comment: @Nasser, it's the same thing as Brett's method, except I put the `Sequence` outside of `With` and used `Hold` to make sure that nothing evaluated prematurely, though I am not sure that is actually needed.  Please see my update, as I think that is the cleaner approach as it does without `Apply`.

Comment: @MrWizard, I am now trying to get your `##&` method to work for embeded macros, which what I really have, and not one level, but need more time. I am making coffee now and should I hope be able to figure it out soon. my example was one level, since I thought it will make no difference. I put an example of what I mean in my update.  But I will try to resolve this myself if I can, it is a challenge :)

Comment: @Nasser, just get rid of your inner `Evaluate` -- I can add an example if it's needed.

Comment: @MrWizard, Thanks! you are right. I was bitten by this before (putting an Evaluate on the inner macro) and forgot all about it. Yes, that was it. It now works very well. I'll add this to my big cheat sheet for Mathematica now.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Sequence`, perhaps like:

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}], 
   Evaluate@With[{im = ImageSize -> Tiny}, 
      Sequence @@ {
         Item[Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Left], 
         Item[Control[{{y, 0, "y="}, 0, 10, 1, im}], ControlPlacement -> Right]
         }
      ]
   ]
```

**Edit**

Same approach, but with a different macro (*warning*, this way leads to madness...)

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[z], {z, -Pi, Pi}], 
   Evaluate @ With[{
      control = Function[{var, name, place}, 
         Item[Control[{{var, 0, name <> "="}, 0, 10, 1, ImageSize -> Tiny}],  ControlPlacement -> place], 
         HoldAll
         ]}, 
   Sequence @@ {control[x, "x", Left], control[y, "y", Right]}
   ]]
```

Comment: Interesting variation.  Are there benefits or disadvantages to either version?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think there's an advantage one way or the other.  My first attempt was similar to yours except I was trying to avoid parentheses and brackets, and `Evaluate@Sequence@@With[...]` has the wrong precedence.

Comment: If nothing else it had the advantage of getting me thinking about putting `Sequence` inside `With` which allowed me to see what I believe is the "correct" way to do this. (See my updated answer.)